# Node Express: handing different params to a URL

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Express app, and ran into a problem that I should know how to solve.

I have this URL that I am trying to GET

```
http://localhost:3000/users/546c2b15a340bb881f853fa6/teams/newTeam
```

however, I get this error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "newTeam" at path "_id"
```

the easy solution would be change my app from this:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/546c2b15a340bb881f853fa6/teams/newTeam
```

into this:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/546c2b15a340bb881f853fa6/newTeam
```

however, I should probably figure out how to parse different params in URLs..any other way good way to fix it?

I believe my app is trying to take "/newTeam" and turn into into an MongoDB _id in this method and that's where things are going wrong:

```
app.param('team_id', function(req, res, next, team_id) {

    var userTeam = TeamModel.getNewTeam(user_db);

      userTeam.findById(team_id, function(err, team) {

        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!team) {
            return new Error("no team matched");
        }
        req.team = team;
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to ask? I am not able to understand your question. From the CastError, I can only say that you are trying to pass value "newTeam" as a mongoDB ID and mongoDB was expecting a ObjectId instead of string value.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I am passing "newTeam" when it is expecting a numeric id, like, "546c3ee5db69044edb488f52". I think the problem is that it doesn't like the capital "T" and it can't parse "newTeam" into a MongoDB _id.

Comment: both "newTeam" or "newteam" are not object ids. So it will not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create routes like this in the following order:

```
app.get("/users/:userId/teams/newTeam", routeHandler1);
app.get("/users/:userId/teams/:team_id", routeHandler2);
```

Now, `app.param("team_id", handler)` will only be called when team_id doesn't contain the value "newTeam".